# notation: why $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$ rather than $\mathbb{P}(\{Y=y\})$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

After reading some formal probability text, I realised the probability is defined on sigma-algebra, in turns the elements enter the probability function supposed to be a set. Rigorously speaking, considering the discrete probability, is the notation suppose to have a bracket inside?

**The former notation comes from intro text, latter is what I thought**

Why $\mathbb{P}(Y=y)$ rather than $\mathbb{P}(\{Y=y\})$

Comment: You are right. Actually, very formally it should be $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\in\Omega: Y(\omega)=y\})$. But writing this all the time might be very annoying, so we use an easier notation.

Comment: It is a matter of convention. As long as we agree on the fact that $Y=y$ means **the set of...**, we don't need curly brackets...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We write the former because it is quicker, easier, and just as understantable.

After all, even $\mathbb P(\{Y=y\})$ is not strictly speaking rigorous. The completely correct formal notation would be

$$\mathbb P(\{\omega\in\Omega: Y(\omega)=y\}).$$

But notation exists to serve us, not the other way around. As long as everyone that reads it understands what we mean, a shorter notation is preferred to a longer, more verbose one.